# windows phone 7 - loading a big xml file

Tags: xml, performance, windows-phone-7, loading, isolatedstorage

I am trying to load a xml file to my app and show it on a ListBox. The problem is that the xml file is about 5 MB, and it takes about 40 seconds on the phone to load. and when the phone locks the screen and returns back it takes another 40 seconds. I tried to use the isolatedstorage to store the data on it but it didn't improve performance. This is my code to load the data:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("BigFile.xml");
            var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("w")
                       orderby (string)query.Element("e")
                       select new myClass
                       {
                           First = (string)query.Element("a"),
                           Second = (string)query.Element("e")
                       };
        ListBox.ItemsSource = data.ToList<myClass>();
```

Is there anyway to speed up the loading?

Comment: Can you measure what's taking the longest time? The XDocument.Load("BigFile.xml") part, or the data.ToList<myClass>() part?

Comment: I'm not sure, but got it faster by using BinaryReader. from 40 seconds to about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To improve performance you can do the following:

- Make sure the loading is moved off the ui thread
- Break the file into multiple smaller ones and load them one at a time and updating the list as you add each one.
- If possible, reformat the data (before adding to the app) so it only includes the absolute minimum data used by the app.
- Convert the file to a different format (try JSON) which can be parsed faster.
- (If using 7.1) put the data in a database and deploy that in the XAP.
- Reconsider the need to have so much data. Large/long lists are hard to browse on a device with a small screen.

Comment: Instead of Json you could go with Binary.  I've found that using System.IO.BinaryWriter/BinaryReader (aka using Write(String)/ReadString()) was about 10times faster than using XML and uses a lot less memory since it doesn't have to load the entire file into memory to parse. http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison/

Comment: I would definitely second eSniff on using a Binary format if that is possible and certainly do the work on a background thread.   I think Matt Lacey's point by far the most important.  You definitely need to consider whether it is wise loading so many items at a time. The phone has very limited resources and your app must not require more than 90mb of RAM to run.  I would urge you to reconsider your approach here otherwise you are going to struggle with performance down the line - not to mention hitting those memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting that code into a background thread to do its stuff while you can get on with other stuff in your main thread.

delcare  "private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;" in the MainPage partial class

Put this code in your MainPage() constuctor (or MainPage_loaded)

// Initiaze background worker do display favourites

```
        if (backgroundWorker == null)
        {
            backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        }
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

and then have your code in here:

```
    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("BigFile.xml");
        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("w")
                   orderby (string)query.Element("e")
                   select new myClass
                   {
                       First = (string)query.Element("a"),
                       Second = (string)query.Element("e")
                   };
    ListBox.ItemsSource = data.ToList<myClass>();

    }
```

Hopefully this should do the trick.