# What does it mean to convert an XML document to binary?

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, binary, xml

I am having a performance issue with `XDocument.Load("large_file.xml")`, where it takes about 25 seconds to load the file.

I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671415/windows-phone-7-loading-a-big-xml-file) that using a binary format could offer up to a 10x performance increase.

What does a binary format look like? How do you go about converting an XML file to it?

Comment: With reference to the comment in the linked question: The binary format suggested is something you have to create yourself.

Comment: Is it just plaintext organized however I see fit?

Comment: Binary is not plain text. The gist of the comments are that XML > JSON > binary. Binary is a format where the number 12345 isn't stored in a line of text containing the characters `12345` but in two bytes `0x39 0x30` (assuming you use a little endian 16 bit word for binary storage). Deciding how to store values in binary format is entirely up to you and if your data is complex this can be non-trivial.

Comment: @Louis you have any sample code for this conversion???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with the implied question:

Q: What is a Binary format?

A: It is a format in which data is represented in a non-textual form.  For example, a Java `int` might be represented as 4 bytes, rather than a sequence of decimal digits and a sign.

Q: What does it look like?

A: If you view it with a text editor / viewer, it looks like garbage.

Q: How do you go about converting an XML file to a binary form?

A: By hand.  Since a binary format is essentially a format (*any* format) that is not text, there is no magical method of converting it.

Q: How and why is a binary format faster?

A: A binary format isn't automatically faster to load than XML (or JSON).  The idea is that you (the programmer) *design* a specific binary format for your application that *will be* faster to load.  You typically do this by such things as:

- avoiding the inclusion of verbose / repetitive structuring information (e.g. XML tag and attribute name),
- using data encodings that require less CPU effort to turn into the in-memory representations,
- avoiding the inclusion of unnecessary metadata,
- avoiding things that require extra in-memory data copying,
- and so on.

Answer (score 3):

There is lots of information in an XML format. So it's big and slow. You can create your own format.

For example:

`<Data>Value</Data>` can be changed to just `value` at a concrete address in a binary file.